# Question Regarding Usage of Verb "Expect'

Tags: word-usage

People often say things like 'It only expects to get worse.' I just want to be on the safe side. You can place an inanimate subject or pronoun like 'it' or 'the rain' before the verb 'expects,' right?

Comment: Actually not.  I've never heard anyone say "It only expects . . .".  "It is raining" is an idiom in itself, a structure not to be pasted on to anything else.  Neither "it" nor "the rain" expect anything.  Look up "expect."  I think only people expect anything.

Comment: I would say "I only expect it to get worse".

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence should be written as: "It *is* only expected to get worse." Or, "It *is* expected to rain."